# Get title of a website silently from a website

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview

I have a link of a website, and I want to get its title.
I tried to do by this code

```
UIWebView* hiddenWebView;
NSString* urlString = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyORxdjGtlk";
            NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [hiddenWebView loadRequest:request];

NSString* text = [hiddenWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```

But the result is: text = NULL;
I just want to get the name of the video

Comment: YouTube has an [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) which you can probably use to figure out video titles.

Comment: I know. But my app has not only youtube link, but also link from another pages

Answer (score 1):

Set the `UIWebView` delegate to your ViewController (for example by ctrl-dragging in Interface Builder) and then:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSURL *url = [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
    NSString *str = [url absoluteString];
    NSString *title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    NSLog(@"%s: url=%@ str=%@ title=%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, url, str, title);
}
```